# Processing clock

Tags: processing.js

I found the Analog clock given in the example http://processingjs.org/learning/basic/clock. 
Is there any other sample that demonstrates the analog clock with 
numbers ?

Comment: Use your trig skills and draw in some numbers. It's just a simple loop!

Comment: Is my adaptation with numbers not good enough? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I have taken Dre's answer, and improved upon it a bit. Now the numbers are in a more appropriate position, and the '0' is now a  '12'.

http://jsfiddle.net/xSrt6/

Answer (score 1):

You may need to modify the code a bit here to put the numbers where you want, but http://jsfiddle.net/FZqZN/4800/